# Fixing border highlight issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have 2 inputs side by side as shown below:

```css
.centered-query-cn {
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
}

.browse-query {
  display: flex;
}

.browse-query input {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="centered-query-cn row">
  <div class="align-self-center">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-10">
        <div class="browse-query">
          <input class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="term" type="text">
          <input class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="location" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

When I click on the LHS input, the border gets highlighted, but it does not look right, as shown below:

[image]

The RHS input hides the highlighted border. Is there anyway I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a relative position for the focused input, so it overlaps the unfocused field.

Anyway for accessibility reasons, actionable elements like inputs should be spaced far enough to make the interface clearer (e.g. you could set a `gap` for `.browse-query`). Also `label` elements for the fields should be provided (placeholders are not enough effective).

```css
.centered-query-cn {
  height: calc(100vh - (334px + 6vh));
  min-height: 340px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.browse-query {
  display: flex;
}

.browse-query input {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1 !important;
}

input:focus {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="centered-query-cn row">
  <div class="align-self-center w-100">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-10">
        <div class="browse-query">
          <input class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="term" type="text">
          <input class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="location" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: you can omit z-index, position:relative can do the job alone. or you only set z-index since input is a flex item so it doesn't need position:relative for z-index to work